# uanble to get callback_query function to work

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram

my code works perfectly fine other than the `if(contents.callback_query)`. I cant seem to get it to get into it so that my other if statement to work. whenever i press the button that is connected to my telegram bot it doesnt seem to project out the message that needs to be sent to the user.

```
function doPost(e) {
  let contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  // the chat id of the user
  let chat_id = contents.message.chat.id; 
  // sending the text that the user sent
  let text = contents.message.text;       
  
  // to have a inline keyboard on the display of the telegram bot
  var keyBoard = {
    "inline_keyboard": [
      [{
        "text": "Box 1",
        "callback_data": "box 1"
      }],
      [{
        "text": "Box 2",
        "callback_data": "box 2"
      }],
      [{
        "text": "All",
        "callback_data": "all"
      }]
    ]
  }
  if(contents.callback_query){ 
    let id_callback = contents.callback_query.from.id;
    let data = contents.callback_query.data; 
    if(data == 'box 1'){
      sendText(id_callback,"hello 1"); // not the correct parameters
    }
    else if(data == 'box 2'){
      sendMessage(id_callback,"hello 2"); // not the correct parameters
    }
    else if(data == 'all'){
      sendMessage(id_callback,"hello 3"); // not the correct parameters
    }
  }
  else if(contents.message){
    sendMessage(chat_id,"Please select one of the options given",keyBoard);
  }
}

function sendMessage(chat_id,text,keyBoard){
    var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id: String(chat_id),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(keyBoard)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', data);
}
```

Comment: please update question with value of `e` or `e.postData.contents`

Comment: i do not understand where does this ```e``` or ```e.postData.contents``` comes from because i am just following codes written by others. and it seems to work